# How can I change the placement of Facet_Wrap labels in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with `ggplot` and I love the `facet_wrap` functionality - it's an absolute necessity given the dimensionality of my data and my figures. However, I find myself unable to customize the plots to the degree I want using `facet_wrap`. Basically, I'd like to place the `facet_wrap` labels inside of the plot area - preferably in the top center-right of each sub-plot, as shown in the attached picture. Unfortunately I can't find any formatting options for `facet_wrap` other than `strip.position`, which doesn't seem to allow for an in-plot placement. `strip.placement` allows for an 'inside' option, but that refers to 'inside the axis', not inside the plot area itself.

I'm concerned the answer may not lie in `facet_wrap` at all. I've previously used `ggarrange` and its customizable labels for similar plots in the past, but given the data I'm working with, I'd like to keep the single step functionality of `facet_wrap`.  Has anyone dealt with this problem before? I've attached sample data and code below.

```
structure(list(Ocean.Regions = c("Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Atlantic", "Southern Ocean", "Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Atlantic", "Southern Ocean", "Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Atlantic", "Southern Ocean", "Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Atlantic", "South Pacific", "Southern Ocean", "Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Atlantic", "South Pacific", "Southern Ocean", "Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Atlantic", "South Pacific", "Southern Ocean", "Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Atlantic", "Southern Ocean", "Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Atlantic", "South Pacific", "Southern Ocean", "Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Atlantic", "Southern Ocean", "Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Atlantic", "South Pacific", "Southern Ocean", "Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Pacific", "South Atlantic", "Southern Ocean", "Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Atlantic", "South Pacific", "Southern Ocean", "Western Tropical Pacific", 
"South Pacific"), binned_alt = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 1000, 
1000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 4000, 4000, 
4000, 4000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 6000, 6000, 6000, 6000, 7000, 
7000, 7000, 7000, 8000, 8000, 8000, 8000, 9000, 9000, 9000, 9000, 
10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 11000, 11000, 11000, 11000, 12000, 
12000), `25%` = c(19.1, 23.95, 14.5, 9.3, 14.9, 12.45, 6.6, 5.9, 
9.15, 5.675, 1.35278884462151, 5.25, 6.3, 4.9, 5.5, 3.3, 5.45, 
3.4, 5.275, 2.375, 5, 3.3, 4.6, 0.688259109311741, 0.561264822134387, 
4.35, 3.575, 0.376811594202899, 0.561264822134387, 3.2, 3.475, 
0.376811594202899, 0.561264822134387, 0.376811594202899, 2.825, 
0.376811594202899, 0.561264822134387, 1.55278884462151, 0.688259109311741, 
0.376811594202899, 0.557971014492754, 4.15, 6.3, 0.376811594202899, 
0.557971014492754, 0.605577689243028, 0.688259109311741, 0.376811594202899, 
0.557971014492754, 0.688259109311741), `50%` = c(24.9, 28.45, 
23.05, 10.1, 18, 17, 9.65, 7.8, 11.7, 9.85, 2.1, 5.7, 8.7, 5.1, 
7.25, 5.4, 7.05, 4.5, 5.65, 3.3, 6.6, 3.7, 7.15, 2.3, 3.65, 6, 
4.45, 0.53253535175732, 3.1, 4.65, 4.75, 0.688259109311741, 0.561264822134387, 
2.8, 9.05, 0.376811594202899, 0.561264822134387, 3.2, 3.5, 0.376811594202899, 
0.561264822134387, 7.5, 14.5, 0.376811594202899, 0.561264822134387, 
0.605577689243028, 0.688259109311741, 0.376811594202899, 0.557971014492754, 
0.688259109311741), `75%` = c(28.3, 33.9, 34.275, 10.8, 23.55, 
19.1, 13.175, 9, 15.85, 16.2, 7.9, 7.775, 11.8, 5.6, 10.3, 6.1, 
9.375, 5.75, 7.175, 5.725, 7.6, 6.45, 7.425, 3.4, 6.325, 7.6, 
6.225, 1.775, 5.1, 7.675, 5.875, 0.688259109311741, 2.925, 5, 
15.725, 1.5, 0.561264822134387, 5.45, 9, 0.605577689243028, 3.6, 
9.675, 23.55, 0.376811594202899, 3.625, 0.605577689243028, 1.69412955465587, 
0.688259109311741, 0.557971014492754, 0.688259109311741)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L))

library(ggplot)
library(ggthemes)
test.plot <- ggplot(SOverflowTest, [![enter image description here][1]][1]aes(y = binned_alt/1000, x = `50%`)) +
  geom_path(size = 1.2) + #geom_point() +
  theme_tufte(base_size = 22) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin =`25%`, xmax = `75%`), height = 0) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black")) +
  facet_wrap(~Ocean.Regions, ncol = 2, as.table = T) +
  xlab("MEK (ppt)") +
  ylab("Altitude (km)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate the facet strips using `element_blank` and put the labels in directly as text:

```
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(SOverflowTest, aes(y = binned_alt/1000, x = `50%`)) +
  geom_path(size = 1.2) + #geom_point() +
  theme_tufte(base_size = 22) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin =`25%`, xmax = `75%`), height = 0) + 
  facet_wrap(~Ocean.Regions, ncol = 2, as.table = T) +
  xlab("MEK (ppt)") +
  ylab("Altitude (km)") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Ocean.Regions, x=18, y=12), 
    data = data.frame(Ocean.Regions = unique(SOverflowTest$Ocean.Regions))) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5),
    axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
    axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"),
    strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]